# Writing from multiline text box to .txt file, and then reading it back

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiline

I have a form with several text boxes and I want to write the contents of each of them to a new line in a .txt file. As in, the user fills in a form, and the info is stored in the file. Then I want to be able to retrieve the info from the file into the same text boxes. I am able to do this, so far, but I encounter problems when one of the text boxes is multiline.

```
Printline(1, txtBox1.text)

Printline(1, txtBox2.text)´which is the multiline one

Printline(1, txtBox3.text)
```

When I read this back from the file I get the second line of the multiline text box where I want the text from txtBox3 to be.

```
LineInput(1, txtBox1.text)

LineInput(1, txtBox2.text)

LineInput(1, txtBox3.text)
```

How can I get all the lines from the multiline text box to write to one line in the file, and then read it back as separate lines in a multiline text box?

I hope I am making sense? I really would like to keep the logic of "one txtBox - one line in the file"

I guess I need to use different methods of writing and reading, but I am not that familiar with this, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on the `Lines` Property in case of having more than one line. Sample code (`curTextBox` is the given `TextBox Control`):

```
Using writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("path", True)
    Dim curLine As String = curTextBox.Text
    If (curTextBox.Lines.Count > 1) Then
        curLine = ""
        For Each line As String In curTextBox.Lines
            curLine = curLine & " " & line
        Next
        curLine = curLine.Trim()
    End If
    writer.WriteLine(curLine)
End Using
```

NOTE: this code puts in one line all the text from the given `TextBox` independently upon its number of lines. If it has more than one line, it includes a blank space to separate the individual lines (all of them fitting in a single line of the file anyway). You might want to change this last feature by adding a different separating character (replace `& " " &` with the one you want).

Comment: I tried your code, and (if I understood it right) it does not seem to do what you said.
If i put the letter "a" in textBox1, and then, say, "b","c" and "d" on separate lines in textBox2, and finally "e" in textBox3. The .txt-file still puts one character on each line. That gives me the same problem when trying to read back from the file.

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen Sorry but this code puts everything in one line. Could you please let me take a look at your exact code?

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen You have to copy this code for each textbox (by replacing curTextBox with the given TextBoxName, that is, textBox1, textBox2 and textBox3). As said, please, let me take a look at your code such that I can find the problem.

Comment: I just had a break-through. It seems to work if I only have the multiline one. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: There is not enough room here to type my code. How do i do it?

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen paste it there, select VB.NET, put any title and send me the link.

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen first thing you are just writing the contents from textBox2 (the other 2 textboxes are being ignored). Also you are not reading the file properly. I can do the required modifications such that it will work as you wish. What you want? write to the file the contents from all the textboxes and then reading the content back?

Comment: exactly! I want the contents fo all 3 textBoxes to write to a file that will be 3 lines long.

Comment: Yeah, I just "commented out" some lines while trying your tip :-)

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen It is a quite improved version. Yesterday I was having a long discussion with andyg0808 about maximising the OO/.NET capabilities and I thought that I had to act accordingly. Purely speaking, you should be the one doing all this, but as far as you don't seem to have too much experience and in order to avoid you to start relying on "not ideal configurations" (.NET is huge and accepts lots of alternatives for each single action), I have thought that better spending a bit of time and doing things properly.

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen It is not the most perfect code for this specific situation; but delivers a pretty clear solution (which you shouldn't find any problem to understand/extend) by relying in a different variety of objects, methods, etc. which you will surely find useful.

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen what I would expect from you is taking your time to understand each single bit to learn how to use the different functionalities I have included; and even extend/improve the code further. Hope that you enjoy it.

Comment: @EspenLilandBjørnsen the code is clear and easily extensible but, logically, is not properly validated (not too much time for that :)); you have information more than enough to do this job by your own. The current version expects that something is written in the 3 textboxes; you would have to improve it to account for further situations (e.g., no text in a textbox). Remember that this site is not expected to work like this, just to-the-point answers to specific problems; but, as explained, I thought was a good moment to (half-)break a rule, don't get used to this :)

Comment: Excelent! Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it!
It works great!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats) the newlines so that they aren't in the output, then unescape them on reading back in.

Here's some example code that will do this (I've never written VB before, so this probably isn't idiomatic):

```vb
' To output to a file:
Dim output As String = TextBox2.Text
' Escape all the backslashes and then the vbCrLfs
output = output.Replace("\", "\bk").Replace(vbCrLf, "\crlf")
' Write the data from output to the file

' To read data from the file:
Dim input As String = ' Put the data from the file in input
' Put vbCrLfs back for \crlf, then put \ for \bk
input = input.Replace("\crlf", vbCrLf).Replace("\bk", "\")
' Put the text back in its box
TextBox2.Text = input
```

Another option would be to store your data in [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [JSON](http://json.org/), or [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). Any of those are text-based formats that will require a library to parse, but should cleanly handle the multiline text you have, along with providing increased future flexibility.

Comment: I am not saying that you cannot improve my answer; but you would have to rely on the lines property anyway (or, at least, on the dimensions of the textbox); but never on the text, as you are suggesting.

Comment: @varocarbas, I'm sorry — it appears that I've been airing my ignorance of VB.NET. I assumed that you read multiline text as a long string with embedded newlines. I see you're right; you have to read each line separately. I do want to point out that your answer does not seem to preserve the individual lines, which is something the OP seemed to want to do ("and then read it back as separate lines in a multiline text box"), and was what I was trying to do with my answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: No problem. But your "our answer does not seem to preserve the individual lines" is not right: it adds a blank space as separation. Nonetheless, I will add a note for the OP; thanks for the comment.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (don't get offended): you have the Visual Studio I guess. Have you tried my code? Do you understand what it is exactly doing? You don't know too much about VB.NET but you know the basics of VB, don't you? and thus you get what the loop does.

Comment: I have to admit, no, I don't have Visual Studio and haven't run your code. My reading of it (this may be ignorance) makes me think that it opens a file, reads the first line of the text box into a variable, then checks if there's more than one line in the text box. If there is, it makes the variable the empty string and then loops through all the lines in the text box, appending them to the string separated by spaces. Once it finishes the loop, it cleans off any extra space. Finally, it writes whatever is in the `curLine` variable to the file and (probably) closes the file. Is that right?

Comment: PERFECT! :) No VS? well... I don't what to say. Anyway... At least, you have learned something about the VB.NET textboxes and that the loops and stuff are pretty similar everywhere.

Comment: It just occurred to me, how is OP getting multiple lines in output if there are no `crlfs` in `txtBoxN.text`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36177/discussion-between-andyg0808-and-varocarbas)

Answer (score 0):

the next simple code works for me.

Saving multiline text to a single line in a file:

```
str = Replace(MyTextBox.Text, Chr(13) & Chr(10), "*LineFeed*") 'something recognizable
Print #1, str 'no quotes
```

To get the string from the file and put it on a TextBox:

```
Line Input #1, str
MyTextBox.Text = Replace(str, "*LineFeed*", Chr(13) & Chr(10))
```

Hope this helps